# socket.on doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.4 LTS but in another same configuration PC it works fine

Tags: node.js, websocket, ubuntu-16.04

This socket connection program works fine on my Digital Ocean server and my other PC.

I would also like to set up this project in my office Ubuntu PC but socket.on can't work. I attached a picture to make it more understandable.

In the picture line 8 works but line 11 doesn't work. 
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnex8.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, instead post the text of the code in your question. However more importantly, "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. If you need people to help you, please explain what doesn't work. Explain what you do - in detail, and how you set up the test that leads to whatever you're doing , explain what you expected to happen, explain what actually happens, include any error messages etc.

Comment: @nos thank you for your response. I'm new here and I'm gonna update my post as you suggest here.